# getting the Origin in cross-domain http requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-domain

I have a website A running on node.js that provides data to various clients. A website B now wants to make javascript calls to my website A in order to obtain the data. I've already added the necessary headers in order to support this.

What I need to add is the way to track the number of requests that come from website B. The problem that I see is that the requests from website B are client-side, so if they have 20 clients using their website I don't see the requests as coming from website B, but from various IPs.

How can I find on my website A that requests originate from website B? I was seeing some mentions of header `Origin`, but requests that I get don't have that header set.

Comment: You could check the http referrer header.

Comment: @Iceman - Isn't referrer header optional ? Most browsers even allow you to deactivate referrer information.

Comment: @Gregor - Do you have access to site B ? Could you just not mark the request going to site A from site B with some sort of token ?

Comment: @DavidDomain I'm aware, but it was the best shot I knew, that is ofcourse if you have no control over Website B. If you do then JWT all the way!

Comment: @Iceman: referer header seems to contain valid value, but it can be disabled/removed I cannot use it

Comment: @DavidDomain: I have access to site B and can add some token. But this would allow exploits where other sites could just also set that token and pretend to be site B

Comment: Use a jwt auth workflow.

Comment: I don't see how jwt solves the problem. It would require that the users of site B need to login to get the token. But site B doesn't require any logging in. I would like to allow all users of site B to have full and free access to make requests to my website A. And my only requirement is ensuring that the requests that I will be processing for free are actually coming from site B.